# Should accessing views done from onStart or onActivityCreated method?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have read several documents about this but still fail to conclude where should I write my codes to set some values in textviews/edittext ...

what i have read and seen in video tutorials is, both onStart and onActivityCreated methods get called with different actions (like after fragment initiated, or orientation changed etc.). Moreover, both of them get called after Activity's onCreate method, which means views are available from both Fragment methods.

Anybody can give me some advise regarding this?

(p.s. Currently I put all codes accessing xml views inside onStart, and my application is running without any issue)

Comment: Either onStart or onActivityCreated will work. One thing to note, is that these are not called if the activty/fragment comes back so any loading of data should be put in the onResume if needed.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any potential problems with accessing your layout's views in onStart or onActivityCreated.

Personally, I usually set references to my layout's views and set initial values in a fragment's [#onViewCreated()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated%28android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle%29).  This is the first opportunity after the layout has been inflated that you have to access a layout's children.  The View that was inflated is passed as a parameter so you even have direct access to the parent layout object if you needed it for some reason.

According to the fragment lifecycle onActivityCreated() will be called next and then onStart().  All of these will be executed in that same order when a fragment is returned from the back stack -- so it seems to be personal preference.